# Execute contents of editable text area

Tags: r, markdown, r-markdown

For a tutorial I am giving, I would like to show some R code in a Rmarkup document producing a plot, and then edit that code live and see the updated plot (for example changing points in the plot to lines).

Ik know I could use RShiny elements to do this, but I would really like to show the R code producing the plot. How can I do this?

Comment: You could fake it by saving the editable code as a string, then having a chunk where you print that string and another chunk where you evaluate it

Comment: Use an R Notebook in RStudio?

Answer (score 1):

The new versions of R Studio act like a notebook, in which the code chunks are evaluated and results displayed right below the chunk. Open a new R Markdown document, insert an R chunk, and Run Current Chunk.

````
```{r}
1+1
```
````

Comment: I mean to execute the code in the resulted knitted document on-the-go. Is that possible?

Comment: No, R markdown only outputs static documents as far as I know. Besides Shiny, the only other browser-based interactive solution I can think of is to use a server-based instance of R for your demo